# multiple get parameter with xf:load

Tags: xml, xforms, exist-db

I'm building a webapplication with eXist as backend.
I wanna load a new ressource with the xf:load element.

What I did is this:

```
<xf:trigger>
  <xf:label>Trigger</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
     <xf:load>
       <xf:resource value="concat('start.xql?floor={$floor}&amp;room={$room}', '')" />
     </xf:load>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

But when I click the trigger this url is loaded:

```
start.xql?floor=0&amp;room=E.01
```

Which is obiviously not desired. When I don't escape the ampersand I get an parsing error:

```
Invalid character in entity name (=) or missing ;
```

So, what is the correct way to pass multiple parameters via the xf:load element?
Can I workaround this problem with the ampersand or am I just missing something?

Thank for any help

Kind regards
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is the URL that is sent?

In XML documents in general, `&` must be written `&amp;` even if they are used in URIs values but their string values are still `&` and the software that will submit the request (the XForms processor in that case) should not be confused...

Anyway, there is another way to deal with query strings in XForms and you could also submit an instance with a query string through HTTP get. The following submission:

should take care of these ampersand "details". You can call it through:

```
<xf:trigger>
  <xf:label>Trigger</xf:label>
  <xf:send ev:event="DOMActivate" submission="trigger-submission"/>
</xf:trigger>
```

assuming of course the right values have been placed in the instance.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I will give your suggestion a try, thanks for your help. I'm gonna let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with XSLTForms after changing the XPath expression for resource/@value because AVT is not required actually... and because XSLTForms doesn't support variables yet:

```
<xf:resource value="concat('start.xql?floor=',floor,'&amp;room=',room)"/>
```

and the FireBug network profiler says:

```
http://localhost/xsltforms/trunk/src/testsuite/misc/start.xql?floor=FL&room=RM
```

So, I think you should better post this issue to the support list of the XForms implementation you are using.

-Alain